# How to enable subdomain -multisite work, when only subdirectory is only shown in network setup?

Tags: multisite

network setup only displays an option to sub-directory sites and sub-domain is not shown, And I am shown the following messages

```
Because your install is in a directory, the sites in your WordPress network must use sub-directories. 

The internet address of your network will be 216.172.171.182.
```

What Can I do to get this to work? Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either install your WordPress installation in your root folder, or change your domain to point to your sub-folder.